# Android aapt high processor utilization (and slow!)

Tags: android, maven-3, aapt

I'm having an issue with Android's `aapt` tool.  I run two development environments.  Each one is on a quad core rig with 8gb of RAM.  One is Windows 7, the other is Ubuntu 10.04.  Both are running Eclipse 3.7r2 and ADT 18.0.

I build with maven.  My build on the linux system takes about 1 minute, and on the windows system it takes 4 minutes.

The performance seems to be cpu-bound on the windows box, since I can see `aapt.exe` taking up a whole core for at least 2 minutes out of the build process.  It executes in a heartbeat on linux.

It doesn't seem to be the png compression issue (as documented [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/DT-i8QK27Iw)) since that was supposed to be fixed in ADT17.

Has anyone else with this issue found a workaround?  Does anyone else have this issue?

Comment: Not sure if it is related, but we compared maven 3.0.3 to maven 2 and saw considerable spikes in cpu usage and time.  Still looking into the latest version (3.0.4) but suspect a general different in the way maven 3 manages its priocesses.

Comment: It's not related to Maven. We are using Ant build scripts and having same problems - full project builds on Linux for less than minute, but same project builds about 5 minutes on Windows. No workaround found yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1907281) speeds up your compiling? It is a fix for the 'slow' standard AAPT tool.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I'll have to give that a try next time I build on Windows.  +1 for making a viable suggestion, in the meantime.

Comment: If i'm reading [this](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/43680/) correct, this fix might be merged with the standard AAPT tool in the future?

Comment: this made my build at least 7 times faster.

Comment: It seems to be fixed in the latest ADT, presumably due to the merge of the patch you linked (or the patch that superseded it).

Comment: Fixed in ADT 21.0.1, so there is no need to download the FAAPT mentioned in the link.